# Setting value of a hidden field in Django form

Tags: django

I'm using `django-registration` to manage my registrations.  I'm trying to force my username and email to be the same in a Django application and I am trying to do it via the registration form as follows:

```
class NoUsernameRegistrationForm(RegistrationForm):
    """
    Form for registering a new user account.

    Requires the password to be entered twice to catch typos.

    Subclasses should feel free to add any additional validation they
    need, but should avoid defining a ``save()`` method -- the actual
    saving of collected user data is delegated to the active
    registration backend.

    """
    username = forms.CharField(
        widget=forms.EmailInput(attrs=dict(attrs_dict, maxlength=75)),
        label=_("Email address"))
    password1 = forms.CharField(
        widget=forms.PasswordInput(attrs=attrs_dict, render_value=False),
        label=_("Password"))
    password2 = forms.CharField(
        widget=forms.PasswordInput(attrs=attrs_dict, render_value=False),
        label=_("Password (again)"))
    email = forms.EmailField(
        widget=forms.HiddenInput(),
        required = False)


    def clean(self):
        """
        Verify that the values entered into the two password fields
        match. Note that an error here will end up in
        ``non_field_errors()`` because it doesn't apply to a single
        field.

        """
        if 'password1' in self.cleaned_data and 'password2' in self.cleaned_data:
            if self.cleaned_data['password1'] != self.cleaned_data['password2']:
                raise forms.ValidationError(_("The two password fields didn't match."))

        """
        Validate that the email address is not already in use.

        """
        try:
            user = User.objects.get(username__iexact=self.cleaned_data['username'])
            raise forms.ValidationError(_("A user with that email address already exists."))
        except User.DoesNotExist:
            self.cleaned_data['email'] = self.cleaned_data['username']
            self.cleaned_data['username']


        return self.cleaned_data
```

The idea is that if passwords match and the `username` is valid then I set the `email` to the `username`.  But I just get the error `(Hidden field email) This field is required`

How should I set this.

Comment: Totally unrelated but the proper syntax for comments is to start the line with a '#' - triple quoted strings are not for comments but for multiline strings.

Comment: You get that error before gettin in the clean method?

Comment: @Bestasttung - thanks.  That's the issue.  I've added     `def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        super(NoUsernameRegistrationForm, self).__init__(*args, **kwargs)
        self.initial['email'] = 'dummy_email@dummy.com'` and it works fine

Comment: I think you can do it directly in the field declaration : 
```forms.EmailField(initial="dummy@gmail.com", other stuff)```

Answer (score 8, accepted):

So for your answer you can do as you said in comment, but directly from the field definition :

```
email = forms.EmailField(
    widget=forms.HiddenInput(),
    required = False,
    initial="dummy@freestuff.com"
)
```

Or just declare a form without an email field (so in your example : `username`, `password1` and `password2`) and treat the username / email part in the form's save method :

```
def save(self, commit=True):
    user = super().save(commit=False) # here the object is not commited in db
    user.email = self.cleaned_data['username']
    user.save()
    return user
```

There you don't have to hide a field with a dummy value, which i think is "cleaner".