# Django adding fields in a form statically

Tags: python, django, django-forms

Good day,

I am trying to make a Django form where I could add fields statically (the concept is described in the figure below).

I want to have a form that would have a button "new". The button "new" should redirect to another page where I could fill the data such as from, to, and amount. Once I press submit it should go back to the form where the filled data should be visible in the form (as amount 1, amount 2 and etc.).

Could somebody lead me on the right path how to start?

P.S. I cannot use javascript

[image]

Code which I am using:

models.py

```
from django.db import models
from django.utils import timezone
from django.contrib.auth.models import User
from django.urls import reverse
from django.forms import inlineformset_factory


class Post(models.Model):
    title_choices = [
        ('Mr', 'Mister'),
        ('Ms.', 'Miss'),
    ]

    title = models.CharField(max_length=100)
    first_name = models.CharField(max_length=100, default = '')
    last_name = models.CharField(max_length=100, default = '')
    date_posted = models.DateTimeField(default=timezone.now)

    titles = models.CharField(
        max_length = 3,
        choices = title_choices,
        default= 'Mr', 
    )

    

    def __str__(self):
        return self.title

    def get_absolute_url(self):
        return reverse('post-detail', kwargs={'pk': self.pk})

class Debt(models.Model):
    Money = models.ForeignKey(Post, on_delete=models.CASCADE, null = True)
    CurrentDebt = models.CharField(max_length=100, default = '')
    Period = models.CharField(max_length=100, default = '')
```

views.py

```
from django.shortcuts import render
from django.views.generic import (
    View,
    ListView,
    DetailView,
    CreateView,
    UpdateView,
    DeleteView,
    TemplateView
)
from .models import Post, Debt
from django.contrib.auth.mixins import LoginRequiredMixin, UserPassesTestMixin
from .latex import tex
from django.http import FileResponse, Http404
from django.urls import reverse
from django.forms import inlineformset_factory, BaseInlineFormSet

FullForm = inlineformset_factory(Post, Debt, fields=('CurrentDebt', 'Period',), extra= 1, can_delete= True)

class PostCreateView(LoginRequiredMixin, CreateView, BaseInlineFormSet):
    model = Post
    fields = ['first_name', 'last_name', 'titles' ,'title']

    def form_valid(self, form):
        form.instance.author = self.request.user # Use this to get the information from the form.
        response = super().form_valid(form)
        return response


class PostCreate2View(LoginRequiredMixin, View):
    
    template_name = 'Blog/form.html'
    model = Debt
    fields = ['CurrentDebt', 'Period']
```

Answer (score 1):

For simplicity, I will use the three rectangle and number them from 1 to 3 going from left to right.

Since you don't have code, I will try and give you a rough blueprint with methods I think can help you. I'm assuming rectangle 2 and rectangle 3 are forms which a user populates data and submitting rectangle 2 adds data to rectangle 1.

The challenges I see are:
1. Having rectangle 2 remember what original data was submitted for `name` and `last_name` once we go to rectangle 3 and back to rectangle 2. 
2. Transmit the data from rectangle 2 back to rectangle 3.

For challenge 1, I would use [a hidden input](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.0/ref/forms/widgets/#hiddeninput). You would have two hidden inputs, one for `name` and one for `last_name`.

For challenge 2, I would use [FormMixin](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.0/ref/class-based-views/mixins-editing/#formmixin). With this mixin, you can use methods like `get_form_kwargs` (see previous link) to pass data from your view to your form. So once you submit rectangle 3, you should redirect the form data to your `GET` request for rectangle 2. From there, you use `get_form_kwargs` and populate your form with appropriate data in its `__init__` method.

Comment: Hi Vincent, I have added a piece of code I am using. Currently in my template I have a button 'New' which is leading to another form. The problem is that neither the primary key nor the author is related between the forms. Rectangle 2 is achieved by utilizing PostCreateView class, Rectangle 3 - Post2CreateView.

Comment: Hi, so if I undedrstand the problem correctly, when you get back to Rectangle 2, the form _forget_ the primary key and the author? Other question, do you have some forms defined in `forms.py` ?

Comment: Yes, you have understood correctly. I do not have any forms defined in forms.py

Comment: I'm very busy these days so I'll try and give you some resources that can help.
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52366940/setting-value-of-a-hidden-field-in-django-form/52367653


https://gist.github.com/vero4karu/ec0f82bb3d302961503d